# How to create a grouped barplot from three columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
  Type Week Value
0  A    1    11
1  A    2     1
2  A    3     7
3  B    1    13
4  B    2    20
5  B    3    30
```

I would like to make a plot like`df.plot.bar()` 
so that it looks like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: `df.pivot('Type','Week','Value').plot.bar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment from @QuangHoang, there are 2 steps to the process.

First, pivot the data.

```py
pivoted = df.pivot('Type', 'Week', 'Value') 
pivoted
# Week   1   2   3
# Type            
# A     11   1   7
# B     13  20  30
```

The reason for this is outlined in the documentation for [DataFrame.plot.bar](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) (emphasis is mine).

> x : label or position, optional. Allows plotting of one column versus
>   another. *If not specified, the index of the DataFrame is used.*
>
> y : label or position, optional. Allows plotting of one column versus
>   another. *If not specified, all numerical columns are used.*

If neither argument is specified, it uses the `Type` index for `x` and every numerical column, now one per week, to get the `y` values for many bars. That's exactly what you want.

```py
pivoted.plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 2):

I used Seaborn to do that plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data=[['A',1,11],['A',2,1],['A',3,7],['B',1,13],['B',2,20],['B',3,30]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Type','Week','Value'])

sns.barplot(x='Type', y='Value', data=df, hue='Week');
```

With Seaborn you can choose properly the X an Y to plot, and using the parameter `hue` to show the values in each week.
Seaborn is based on matplotlib, so the functions you use in plt are applied in Seaborn too (like `plt.legend()`, `plt.xlabel()`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `pandas` solution is the one provided by @Quang Hoang if you have tidy datasets as in your case you could use `seaborn` as suggested by @Leonardo Araújo or `plotly` (which returns a nice interactive plot) as in the following

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = [['A',1,11],
        ['A',2,1],
        ['A',3,7],
        ['B',1,13],
        ['B',2,20],
        ['B',3,30]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Type','Week','Value'])

# you need this as you want week to be category and not continuous
df["Week"] = df["Week"].astype(str)
px.bar(df, x="Type", y="Value", color="Week", barmode="group")
```

[image]